# Excel 2013 Hide Page Breaks by default in Normal View

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I exclusively use Excel 2014 in Normal view, and I never ever use the dotted page break lines. I know I can turn them off with File > Options > Advanced > Uncheck "Show Page Breaks." I want this to be the default for all sheets in all new workbooks, rather than manually turning them off every time. Is that possible?

Comment: In the Immediate console (Alt + F11 -> Ctro + G), execute the following command: **ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False**

Comment: This works well for the active workbook. Is there a way I can have this be the default setting for new workbooks?